# How to fill in rows based on event type data

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, group-by

So my table has 2 columns: hour and customerID. Every customer will have 2 rows, one corresponding to hour that he/she came into the store, and one corresponding to hour that he/she left the store. With this data, I want to create a table that has every hour that a customer has been in the store. For example, a customer X entered the store at 1PM and left at 5PM, so there would be 5 rows (1 for each hour) like the screenshot below.

Here's my attempt that's now:

```
select
    hour
    ,first_value(customer_id) over (partition by customer_id order by hour rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as customer_id
FROM table
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Postgres <> Snowflake. Please tag only the one database that you are using.

Comment: What if a customer has more than two rows (say, the same customer comes back to the store later on)?

Comment: What is the datatype of the `hour` column?

Comment: @GMB - removed Snowflake. hour is timestamp truncated to the nearest hour

Comment: @GMB - We can assume every customer has 2 rows (one for entry and one for exit), and any customerIDs that deviate away are filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you are running Postgres
- a given customer always has exactly two rows in the table
- `hour` is of a date-like datatype

Then one option is to use `generate_series()` with a lateral join, like so:

```
select t.customer_id, x.hour
from (
    select customer_id, min(hour) min_hour, max(hour) max_hour 
    from mytable 
    group by customer_id
) t
cross join lateral generate_series(min_hour, max_hour, '1 hour') x(hour)
order by t.customer_id, x.hour
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d7339716929703875fb989260bf1f2e2)**:

```
customer_id | hour               
:---------- | :------------------
X           | 2019-04-01 13:00:00
X           | 2019-04-01 14:00:00
X           | 2019-04-01 15:00:00
X           | 2019-04-01 16:00:00
X           | 2019-04-01 17:00:00
Y           | 2019-04-01 17:00:00
Y           | 2019-04-01 18:00:00
Y           | 2019-04-01 19:00:00
```