# How to fill in rows based on available data

Tags: sql, date, select, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowflake SQL.

So my table has 2 columns: hour and customerID. Every customer will have 2 rows, one corresponding to hour that he/she came into the store, and one corresponding to hour that he/she left the store. With this data, I want to create a table that has every hour that a customer has been in the store. For example, a customer X entered the store at 1PM and left at 5PM, so there would be 5 rows (1 for each hour) like the screenshot below.

Here's my attempt that's now:

```
select
    hour
    ,first_value(customer_id) over (partition by customer_id order by hour rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as customer_id
FROM table
```

[image]

Comment: what happens when a customer leave and returns. You have not state to handle multiple daily transactions. Also why did you not apply any of the lessons from asking this exact question for postgres to this question. And for you first value the window range values are adding no value, as first value by and order will never pick a "later value". Lastly calling the column hour, when it has a date in the value is not quite correct, and is your data constrained to one day, thus the date is of not use, or is the date useful, and thus intended also be partitioned by

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879511/how-to-fill-in-rows-based-on-event-type-data
given you have done "nothing" to progress your thinking from this question, a better choose would be "how in snowflake do a `cross join lateral generate_series` as that does not seem to work" type question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snowflake, you would typically use a table of numbers to solve this. You can use the `table (generator ...)` syntax to generate such derived table, and then join it with an aggregate query that computes the hour boundaries of each client with an inequality condition:

```
select t.customer_id, dateadd(hour, n.rn, t.min_hour) final_hour
from (
    select t.customer_id, min(t.hour) min_hour, max(t.hour) max_hour 
    from mytable t
    group by t.customer_id
) t
inner join (
    select row_number() over(order by null) - 1 rn 
    from table (generator(rowcount => 24))
) n on dateadd(hour, n.rn, t.min_hour) <= t.max_hour
order by customer_id, final_hour
```

This would handle up to 24 hours of visit per customer. If you need more, then you can increase the parameter to the table generator.

Comment: apologies for the duped post, tried doing it myself for snowflake implementation but no success.

Comment: `row_number` should be `row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

so for the example case as shown in the test data, where there is only one days worth of data GMB's solution works fine.

once you get into many days (that can/cannot have overlapping store visits, lets just pretend you cannot overnight in the store)

which can be fixed via:

```
select t.hour::date, t.customer_id, min(t.hour) min_hour, max(t.hour) max_hour 
from mytable t
group by 1,2
```

but multiple entries, ether requires tag data like:

```
with mytable as (
  select * from values 
    ('2019-04-01 09:00:00','x','in')
    ,('2019-04-01 15:00:00','x','out')
    ,('2019-04-02 12:00:00','x','in')
    ,('2019-04-02 14:00:00','x','out')
   v(hour, customer_id, state)
)
```

or for it to be inferred:

```
with mytable as (
  select * from values ('2019-04-01 09:00:00','x','in'),('2019-04-01 15:00:00','x','out')
     ,('2019-04-02 12:00:00','x','in'),('2019-04-02 14:00:00','x','out')
   v(hour, customer_id, state)
)
select hour::date as day
    ,hour
    ,customer_id
    ,state
    ,BITAND(row_number() over(partition by day, customer_id order by hour), 1) = 1 AS in_dir
from mytable
order by 3,1,2;
```

giving:

```
DAY           HOUR                   CUSTOMER_ID    STATE    IN_DIR
2019-04-01    2019-04-01 09:00:00    x              in       TRUE
2019-04-01    2019-04-01 15:00:00    x              out      FALSE
2019-04-02    2019-04-02 12:00:00    x              in       TRUE
2019-04-02    2019-04-02 14:00:00    x              out      FALSE
```

now this can be used with a LAG and QUALIFY to get true ranges the can handle multi-entries:

```
select customer_id
    ,day
    ,hour
    ,lead(hour) over (partition by customer_id, day order by hour) as exit_time
from infer_direction
qualify in_dir = true
```

which works by getting then next time for all rows of each day/customer, and after that (via the qualify) only keeping the rows 'in' rows.

then we can then join to the time of a day:

```
select dateadd('hour', row_number() over(order by null) - 1, '00:00:00'::time) as hour
from table (generator(rowcount => 24))
```

thus for it all woven together

```
with mytable as (
  select hour::timestamp as hour, customer_id, state 
  from values 
     ('2019-04-01 09:00:00','x','in')
     ,('2019-04-01 12:00:00','x','out')
     ,('2019-04-02 13:00:00','x','in')
     ,('2019-04-02 14:00:00','x','out')
     ,('2019-04-02 9:00:00','x','in')
     ,('2019-04-02 10:00:00','x','out')
   v(hour, customer_id, state)
), infer_direction AS (
  select hour::date as day
      ,hour::time as hour
      ,customer_id
      ,state
      ,BITAND(row_number() over(partition by day, customer_id order by hour), 1) = 1 AS in_dir
  from mytable
), visit_ranges as (
  select customer_id
      ,day
      ,hour
      ,lead(hour) over (partition by customer_id, day order by hour) as exit_time
  from infer_direction
  qualify in_dir = true
), time_of_day AS (
    select dateadd('hour', row_number() over(order by null) - 1, '00:00:00'::time) as hour
    from table (generator(rowcount => 24))
)
select t.customer_id
    ,t.day
    ,h.hour
from visit_ranges as t
join time_of_day h on h.hour between t.hour and t.exit_time
order by 1,2,3;
```

we get:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    DAY           HOUR
x              2019-04-01    09:00:00
x              2019-04-01    10:00:00
x              2019-04-01    11:00:00
x              2019-04-01    12:00:00
x              2019-04-02    09:00:00
x              2019-04-02    10:00:00
x              2019-04-02    13:00:00
x              2019-04-02    14:00:00
```

Comment: that's a clever implementation. For right now, GMB's solution serves the need perfectly. But will revisit your suggestion for future for sure.